# How to Lock In Excel References

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm working on correcting these large two excel sheets. I need the sequence of entries to match up and I need to make sure they both have all of the same entries.

To check for this I created two extra supporter sheets to show me the work that needs to be done. One that shows me if the order of entries match up and one to show me which ones are not entered in the other sheet.

I created the first one with a simple side-by-side column comparison. **Column A** references the entries in ***sheet1*** and **Column B** references ***sheet2***. And I have Column C simply doing a match comparison between the two. Showing True or False.

The second supporter sheet follows the side-by-side comparison as the first and finds discrepancies via conditional formatting, coloring in a cell if it does not match any of the other entries in the opposite column (this was done with two rules).

---

The issue is that when I update either ***sheet1*** or ***sheet2*** by inserting a new row on one of the sheets my references in my supporter sheets no longer align. Some show the #Ref! error though some simply show and incremented reference. (i.e. $A7 when I still want $A6).

My formula for **Column A** and **Column B** are simply `="sheet1"$A6` and `="sheet2"$B4`.

It might be noteworthy that ***sheet1*** and ***sheet2*** are actually different files.

---

Is there any way to lock in my references? So they always reference that particular cell? Even when I insert a new one in the worksheets they reference?

Comment: Use absolute references ="sheet1"$A$6 and  ="sheet2"$B$4

Comment: If you're saying that `="sheet1"$A6` becomes say `="Sheet1"$A7` when inserting a new row, you want to use `Indirect()`. i.e. `=Indirect("'Sheet1'!$A$7")` I believe.

Comment: @yass Absolute References are not what I'm going for. Because I do want the next row to increment. Is there an easy way to use $A$6 so that it increments with every row?

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't think that INDIRECT will help, because I am referencing the direct cell I want to populate the cell. Not another reference.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear enough. I updated the post to try and clear things up.

Comment: `Is there any way to lock in my references? So they always reference that particular cell? Even when I insert a new one in the worksheets they reference?` Answer: NO. You are asking can I reference A4 even when I add a row? NO. A4 is row A, Column 4 always and forever. However if you want continuous alignment, whatever you do with one sheet you have to do to all sheets. And don't use the $$ references if you plan on adding rows and columns. Remember too, if you add or delete, do it for all.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Formula:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)="","",INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&"R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE))
```

Even if you insert Row it will always reference the same cell as where the formula is because of RC reference and you can drag it down and in the same row

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. What does `&"R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN()` represent? Just a general cell? And why are you just checking if it equates to ','?

Comment: I just want my cell to populate the same cell location when I insert a new row in the sheet it references. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: &"R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN() is the reference of the same cell in another sheet using R1C1 reference (number of row R and number of column C) instead of A6 try it